split a string using whitespace as the delimiter containing '-' character
I want to split a string containing - as first character using white space as the delimiter. But the following code seems not working. If I remove the - character then it splits correctly. This is the script
#!/bin/bash

string="-e -/a/b/c/d"
arr=($string)
arrLen=${#arr[@]}
echo $arrLen
echo ${arr[0]} #prints empty
if [ $arrLen = 2 ] && [ ${arr[0]} = "-e" ]; then #this condition gets passed surprisingly
    echo "Hi ${arr[1]}"
fi

Output
2

Hi -a/b/c/d


Have you ever though of that echo -e has a special meaning? Try printf '%s\n' "${arr[0]}"

@j6t yeah -e option enables interpretation of backslash escapes. But I just want to print it here. I tried putting quotes around but no luck

Output is as expected, isn't it? What is your question?

This is why you don’t use echo.

Some versions of echo will (correctly) print the string -e -/a/b/c/d when given those arguments.  Many versions of echo will treat the -e as a flag and use it to modify how the subsequent arguments are printed.   Don't use echo; you never know which version you'll get.

The leading -- doesn't work on many versions of echo.

This question is similar to: I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo).

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Your split is working fine. Your test is broken.
Just to put what has already been answered in comments into a clear example -
$: echo "-e"            # -e is taken as an option to echo

$: echo "[$x]"          # with other data to ameliorate
[-e]

$: printf '%s\n' "-e"   # here's it's just a string
-e

Short answer; just use printf.
The longer answer is better explored here, and maybe by reading over the man page for echo itself.
As a quick aside, echo is unfortunately one of the few utilities that can't use -- to disable further arguments... because you might want to print out a pair of dashes. You can with printf.
$: echo -- "-e"
-- -e

$: printf '-v %s\n' "-e" "bar"     # confused by -v
bash: printf: ` %s\n': not a valid identifier

$: printf -- '-v %s\n' "-e" "bar"  # fixed
-v -e
-v bar

And if you just need to print out that pair of dashes, you still can.
$: printf '-- -v %s\n' "-e" "bar"     # this confuses it
bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

$: printf -- '-- -v %s\n' "-e" "bar"  # but this fixes that
-- -v -e
-- -v bar

